# Template specialization - different behaviour between MSVC and GCC/MinGW

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, gcc, mingw

I specialized a template and encountered a different beahviour between the MSVC compiler and MinGW/GCC. Here is the header file:

```
// MyClass.h
#ifndef MYCLASS_HEADER
#define MYCLASS_HEADER

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
   virtual void doSomething() {
      // some code
   }
};

// specialization prototype here

#endif
```

Now, the difference. To avoid multiple definitions, i specialized only a prototype in the header file, the implementation is in a cpp file. The specialization is the problem. the GCC/MinGW compiler accepts only this one:

```
template<> void MyClass<int>::doSomething(); // GCC version
```

And MSVC only this:

```
extern template void MyClass<int>::doSomething(); // MSVC version
```

The implementation in the CPP file is the same for both:

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

template<> void MyClass<int>::doSomething() {
   // some code
}
```

with the GCC prototype the MSVC compiler throws an "unresolved external symbol" error, GCC with the MSVC version throws "specialization of ... after instantiation".

At the moment, i have the workaround:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
extern template
#else
template<>
#endif
void MyClass<int>::doSomething();
```

in the header file. It works, but i don't like it. Is there a way to avoid the compiler specific switch?

Comment: What versions of MSVC and GCC are you using?

Comment: MSVC 2010 SP1 and GCC 4.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not the same thing:

```
template<> void MyClass<int>::doSomething(); // GCC version

extern template void MyClass<int>::doSomething(); // MSVC version
```

The first one declares an explicit *specialization*, the second one declares an explicit *instantiation*.

> with the GCC prototype the MSVC compiler throws an "unresolved external symbol" error, GCC with the MSVC version throws "specialization of ... after instantiation".

The GCC error is telling you that there has been an implicit instantiation of `MyClass<int>::doSomething()` earlier in the file than the declaration of the explicit specialization; that is a bug in your code.  You must declare the explicit specialization before any use of it that causes an implicit instantiation, otherwise that implicit instantiation will use the primary template definition, not the specialization.  You can usually ensure that the specialization is declared before it's used by declaring it directly after the definition of the primary template, before any instantiations of `MyClass<int>`.

I don't know why you get the MSVC error, it sounds as though you are failing to link to `MyClass.cpp`.  If that's not it, you could try adding an explicit instantiation definition to `MyClass.cpp` to force the symbol to be emitted in that file:

```
template void MyClass<int>::doSomething();  // N.B. no "extern" on definition
```

Have you tried declaring  **both** the specialization and instantiation, but ensuring they are declared **before** any implicit instantiations?  That should be valid C++ e.g.

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
public:
   virtual void doSomething() {
      // some code
   }
};
// declare explicit specialization
template<> void MyClass<int>::doSomething();
// declare explicit instantiation
extern template void MyClass<int>::doSomething();
#endif
```

.

```
// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

// define explicit specialization
template<> void MyClass<int>::doSomething() {
   // some code
}
// define explicit instantiation
template void MyClass<int>::doSomething();
```

Alternatively, if you can't make that work with both compilers, you could put the definition of the specialized member function in the header and declare it `inline`, which would also avoid multiple definition errors.

Comment: `inline` solved the problem. now, i have the definition in the header file: `template<> inline MyClass<int>::doSomething() { /*code*/ }` works for both compilers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard says extern is correct, might be a bug in some implementations:

Excerpt from 14.7.2 Explicit instantiation:

"The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
**extern**<sub>opt</sub> **template** *declaration*

There are two forms of explicit instantiation: an explicit instantiation deﬁnition and an explicit instantiation declaration. An explicit instantiation declaration begins with the extern keyword."

Comment: Standard also says "_An explicit specialization of any of the following [...] -member function of a class template [...] can be declared by a declaration introduced by `template<>`_". In despite of is very interesting to know what compiler works fine, that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then I suppose my answer is no, you're probably doing it the best way until compiler conformance increases.

Comment: `extern` is correct **if you want to declare an explicit instantiation** ... it's not clear that's what the OP wants to do though